# One service per day, per person if client is served at the same location

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

How can I write my query to retrieve data showing One service per day, per person if the client is served at the same enrolment location also if the same client is served at different enrolment location same day, the service should be displayed.

PS: el = enrolment location, sl= service location, service date is datetime2 so present different times.

Example raw data

```
ClientID  serviceID   clientname       sl          el         service date
  1         112         sam          atlanta     atlanta       04/01/2017
  1         113         sam          atlanta     atlanta       04/01/2017
  1         114         sam          augusta     atlanta       04/01/2017
  1         115         sam          atlanta    montgomery     04/01/2017
  1         116         sam          atlanta    atlanta        04/02/2017
  2         117         joy          delaware   delaware       04/02/2017
  2         118         joy          delaware   delaware       04/02/2017

Expected result for service dates between 04/01/2017 and 04/03/2017

ClientID  serviceID   clientname       sl          el         service date
  1         112         sam          atlanta     atlanta       04/01/2017
  1         114         sam          augusta     atlanta       04/01/2017
  1         115         sam          atlanta    montgomery     04/01/2017
  1         116         sam          atlanta    atlanta        04/02/2017
  2         118         joy          delaware   delaware       04/02/2017
```

Comment: Just do SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, ServiceID, Cluentname, sl,el FROM YourTablr

Comment: Sorry for typos, typed above on my phone. also should have included the service data column in the above

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to use `GROUP BY` to resolve the duplicate records.  If I read your question correctly, there should only be one record per each client, service location, enrollment location, and given date.  This implies that we should `GROUP BY` the following columns:

```
ClientID, clientname, sl, el, [service date]
```

Note that I include the `clientname` as well so that this can appear in the result set.  For the `serviceID`, I arbitrarily choose the minimum value per group, which appears to agree with what you expect.

```
SELECT
    ClientID,
    MIN(serviceID) AS serviceID,
    clientname,
    sl,
    el,
    [service date]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ClientID,
    clientname,
    sl,
    el,
    [service date]
```

Comment: Thanks much Tim but it didn't do the trick you see its a long script and I will use for SSRS and grouping by all those columns,,,, Do you have another method I can try. Thanks for all you do.

Comment: @HenryAmadi An alternative would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, but even in that case we would need to list the same columns for the partition.  You should have given a better example more reflective of your actual problem.